# Fortran Help, open statement error any idea?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran77, fortran95

I have some Fortran error code in (open) statement like the following:

```
!IF ITS THE FIRST CALL TO THIS UNIT, DO SOME BOOKKEEPING
IF (INFO(7).GE.0) GO TO 100
!FIRST CALL OF SIMULATION, CALL THE TYPECK SUBROUTINE TO CHECK THAT THE
!USER HAS PROVIDED THE CORRECT NUMBER OF INPUTS,PARAMETERS,AND DERIVS
INFO(6)=NO
INFO(9)=1
CALL TYPECK(1,INFO,NI,NP,ND)
open (unit=99,file='debug99.dat',status='replace',buffered='no')
RETURN 99
!END OF THE FIRST ITERATION BOOKKEEPING
```

The error would be the following:

```
| open (unit=99,file='debug99.dat',status='replace',buffered='no')
|                                                  1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
```

Any idea how to solve this?